# Compare Versions in a function

Tags: javascript

```
function compareVersions (version1, version2) {
 if (version1 >= version2) {
  return true;
 }
 else {
  return false;
 }

compareVersions("11", "10");                    // returns true
compareVersions("11", "11");                    // returns true
compareVersions("10.4.6", "10.4");              // returns true
compareVersions("10.4", "11");                  // returns false
compareVersions("10.4", "10.10");               // returns false
compareVersions("10.4.9", "10.5");              // returns false
```

The compareVersions("10.4", "10.10"); its not comparing with the subversion, so its gonna be true. How can i fix this?

Comment: It is comparing, but `10.4` is greater than `10.10`

Comment: The 10.10 is greater than 10.4 , but is returning true because it is comparing 10 > = 10 , and not with subversion .

Comment: dot separated version numbers are not the same as decimal numbers. You'll need to parse the version and compare appropriately.

Comment: [JavaScript compare version numbers site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+compare+version+numbers+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 0):

```
function compareVersions(v1, v2){
    var _v1 = v1.split('.');
    var _v2 = v2.split('.');

    var i=0;
    for(; i<_v1.length && i<_v2.length && _v1[i]*1==_v2[i]*1; i++);
    return !(_v1[i]*1<_v2[i]*1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the comparisons are only meaningful with a context. 
It is assumed (horrible word) that you are complying with [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/).

If so, you could use a library that deals with this more completely, such as https://github.com/npm/node-semver

Without such context, you have to worry about "1.0.0-alpha" being compared to "1.0.0" and so on.